# PyQt4 Custom Widgets

Tags: python, widget, pyqt4

Are there any good PyQt4 custom widgets like at [Qt-Apps.org](http://www.qt-apps.org/index.php?xcontentmode=4298&PHPSESSID=fe445ee4c63f527a6ac528a3312f66e6)?

I would like to start making PyQt custom widgets but online resources that I find don't seem to be clear

For example, [Trolltech's](http://doc.trolltech.com/qq/qq26-pyqtdesigner.html) and [Zetcode's](http://zetcode.com/tutorials/pyqt4/customwidgets/)  don't seem to be related in any way at all.

Thanks for any input :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be PyQt examples of all C++ Qt examples in your PyQt4 distribution. I have them here: `/usr/share/doc/python-qt4-doc/examples`. Theye are quite good for the start. When you understand them, it should also be fairly easy for you to port some C++ examples to PyQt code or turn C++ custom widgets to C++.

Answer (score 0):

online resources about PyQt aren't really that rampant, so any information/projects would be welcomed. Don't hesitate to post links to your upcoming widgets or anything else.

I would be really glad to work on that with you as i'm learning more about pyqt as well.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for tutorials on making custom PyQt widgets, or looking for a library of them?

I've been developing a library of reusable custom widgets if that's what you're looking for - at somepoint will be getting to the tutorials, but they aren't there yet.

Check out projexsoftware.com, specifically the ProjexUI framework:

http://dev.projexsoftware.com/projects/projexui

http://docs.projexsoftware.com/sdk-reference/projexui-sdk

In looking at it, I'll need to get some images up there...but there's a Calendar widget, Gantt Chart, View plugin system, Node view, Chart widgets, along with a number of extensions to the base Qt widget classes.

Also the easiest way to see the majority of the widgets is in the Qt Designer - so if you have it setup to work with PyQt plugins, wherever you install the projexui library you can add the /path/to/projexui/designer/build to your PYQTDESIGNERPATH and it'll load designer with our plugins.

Comment: Links are broken